# Javascript Websockets Disconnect on Page Unload

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am working to build an online game using python flask and web technologies that uses web sockets to allow the game to run live. One page of the game is a lobby, on which all the current players are displayed. If a user disconnects from the game, they should, of course be removed from the lobby list.

I figured that in order for the user to disappear from the list promptly, the client's browser will need to manually send the disconnect executing `socket.disconnect()` or by sending another custom event when the page unloads.

Unfortunately I just can't seem to get this to run using the `onunload` event - it runs when the page loads, not when you leave the page. I also can't find a way to use the `onbeforeunload` event as I'm already using this to display a confirmation pop-up.

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

My client side code:

```
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {if (!intentionalForward) {event.preventDefault(); event.returnValue = " "}});
    window.addEventListener("unload", function () { socket.emit("test","testing unload event"); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working properly by forcing the client to connect using the websocket transport (by adding the `{transports: ["websocket"]}` flag to my `io.connect` function). This means that the disconnect event now works on the server.

N.B. I was required to install and use gunicorn from this point as the flask development server does not support websockets.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is, you call `socket.emit` and assign result of that call as event listener to `unload` event. You should use a closure function like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("unload", function() { socket.emit("test","testing unload event"); });
```

Comment: On top of this `beforeunload` and `unload` can be unreliable and handled differently by browsers. The main thing is you should also be checking if the client is connected from the server by sending 'ping' requests from server -> client at an interval eg. 60 seconds and waiting for the client to response, then tracking who isn't responding after x amount of pings.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, unfortunately this hasn't made any difference. :( Indeed I had got it written like this earlier in my testing but I thought at least it did _something_ with it written as I had it - now I know why.

Comment: @DoubleJG that will always be the fallback option but I want it to be, in most cases, more responsive than can be achieved with pings. I am modelling aspects of my game off a website called Kahoot which we used to play at school. My investigation of that site suggests that if you close your browser normally then you will disconnect instantly from the game list but if you kill it, for example using task manger, it takes a number of seconds before your name is removed from everyone else's list.